# WordPressのカスタムHTMLで貼り付けると、サイトを表示の場合は大きさは大きいまま（プレビューにすると大きさは変わる）

Tags: wordpress

#### やりたいこと

カフェサイトのアクセスのページで地図の大きさを小さくしたい。

#### 起きている問題やエラーメッセージ

Googleマップで地図の大きさを中から小に変更してWordPressのカスタムHTMLで貼り付けると、サイトを表示の場合は大きさは大きいまま（プレビューにすると大きさは変わる）

#### 試したこと

カスタムサイズを1200✖️400▶︎HTMLをコピーして貼り付けてもサイズが変わらない。

"WordPress 地図を埋め込む 大きさ" とGoogleで検索したが全く答えに辿り付けなかった。